# Is caching certain parts of a page possible?

Tags: 7, theming, caching, commerce

I have created a drupal 7 commerce site that displays some real time data to visitors as current number of purchases, upcoming products in the next day or so etc. Is there a way to cache parts of the site / page so that not everything is reconstructed on every request?
For example for each product everything can be cached except from the number of current purchases, so I would like to cache images, prices, theme etc, but not the number of current purchases. 
Is it possible?

Comment: Are the users logged-in at this point? Drupal have different caching option depending on if the user is logged-in or not.

Comment: Both, users can be either visitors or logged in at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the [Page manager](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) together with [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels), then yes, this is trivial. Each "Pane", in a Panel can have it's own cache settings, and they can also be set on a per user basis, meaning you can cache things, even if they include data that is unique for the logged in user.

If you also add [Cache actions](http://drupal.org/project/cache_actions) on top of that, you can add some really aggressive caching that will be cleared only, and exactly, when the relevant data updates.

Comment: I do have Ctools enabled but the nodes are displayed through views using tpl.php files for formatting. If I remember correctly from D6, panels where used to assemble a page from different fields, so no I am not currently using panels, as the job is done by theme files.

Comment: Using Panels is the only way I'm aware of for solving your problem.

Comment: Since this seems to be the only way possible I have marked this answer as correct. I 'll probably try and use panels sometime in the future. Until then I will have no caching.